# Razor page select component to acquire selectedItem and route multiple values

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

ASP .Net Core 6.0 Razor page contains a select component that I want to use for filtering the data presented on the page. The code behind processes for both get and post. Most of the get operation provides the list for for the Razor page filter selection. Two pieces of information need to be routed back to the getter. Everything tried so far will only send back one value or the other, not both. The button only sends the currentFilter. The onchange doesn't fire so the link never gets a valid @selectedFilter.

*Section that provides the drop-down list:*

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by Department:
            <select name="currentFilter" asp-for="@Model.DepartmentFilter" asp-items="@Model.DepartmentNameSL"
                onchange="OnChangeMethod()">
                <option value="">-- Department Filter --</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@Model.Student.ID" /> 
            <a asp-page="./Enroller" asp-route-id="@Model.Student.ID" asp-route-currentFilter="@selectedFilter"  >Try Update List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

It is the code section on the page that brings me here. Documentation for Razor pages does not seem to support what my IDE will use. @{ ... } will allow code development. All example code uses @code { ... }, but the keyword 'code' is not recognized. In fact many keywords are not recognized; i.e. 'private', 'public', 'override' for example. Plus the code section has to come before the HTML or 'selectedFilter' is not recognized.

```
@{
    string selectedFilter = string.Empty
    //void OnChangeMethod(EventArgs e) => selectedFilter = e.ToString();
    void OnchangeMethod()
    {
        selectedFilter = "selection made";
    }
}
```

It is like I'm missing a package or documentation has not kept up with .Net 6, or .Net 6 dropped much of what used to be in prior versions or I am in some episode of the Twilight Zone and don't know it.

The HTML will get the value set in the code but it will not change it nor call the OnChangeMethod. It seems to me that the lines between Razor and Blazor are blurred and perhaps my difficulty lies there. So finding documentation that puts information in the right order would be helpful.

Comment: You can read [razor-pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to see the difference between them. Maybe you can use Razor component in the Razor pages project, but cannot add `@code` of the `.razor` in the `.cshtml` of the razor page , you can try to use javascript in .cshtml  by  `<script>`  to meet your goal.

Comment: @Quing Guo  Thanks for reply. I'll check out your references. I did try <script> but the property defined within was not reachable from where I needed to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the solution was very simple. What needed to take place was to include the target identifier "id" with the selected filter. The standard button for submit would then include both.

```
"{id:int?}"
```

route template was added after the @Page directive. Can't believe I missed it. But it would be helpful to know how to make the event calls work.